# Alternative to evaluating a string using a function

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to output a list of records but some may not have a value in the subject column.
I have an altSubject column that would specify what to output instead.

**simplified for example**

```
insert all 
    into myTable 
        (id, subject, altSubject, partNumber, serialNumber, startDate, endDate) 
        values
        (1, 'test',null,'xyz','123','1/1/2019', '1/5/2019') 
    into myTable 
        (id, subject, altSubject, partNumber, serialNumber, startDate, endDate) 
        values
        (2, null, '''SN: '' || serialNumber','abc','789','1/1/2019', '1/5/2019')
```

output should look like:

```
subject | Part Number | Start Date | End Date
test    | xyz         | 1/1/2019   | 1/5/2019
SN: 789 | abc         | 1/1/2019   | 1/5/2019
```

I've been able to do this using a case with a function below but the problem I'm having is it takes 5 minutes to run on a 40k row table.

```
select
    ...
    ...
    case when altSubject is not null then
        fAltSubject(id,altSubject)
    else
      subject
    end subject
from
    myTable
where
    status = 'closed'
```

the function:

```
create or replace function fAltSubject
    (pID in number
    , pAltSubject in varchar2)
    return varchar2 
  as
    vNewSubject varchar2(400) := '';
  begin
    vSql := 'select ' ||
      pAltSubject ||
      ' from
          myTable
        where
          id = ' || pID;
    execute immediate vSql
     into 
       vNewSubject;
    return vNewSubject;
end faltsubject;
```

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't take 5 minutes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using *bind arguments* (see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm)) will allow you to speed up you function. And see also [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables)

Comment: @SternK thank you. I tried `execute immediate 'select :newSubject from myTable where id = :id' into vNewSubject using pAltSubject, pID` but the result was `'SN: ' ||  serialNumber` instead of `SN: 789` am I missing something?

Comment: See [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158489/native-dynamic-sql-execute-immediate-with-column-and-table-names). A bind variable is a value or value address, not a table or column name.

Comment: so looking at my example and desired solution, how were you suggesting I use the bind variables?

Comment: Something like this `execute immediate 'select ' || pAltSubject || ' from myTable where id = :id' into vNewSubject using pID`.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but it still took 5 and a half minutes.

Comment: Is it correct assumption that all columns from your mask belong to the `myTable` table?

Comment: What is the percentage rows with filled `subject` and `altSubject`?

Comment: @sternk of the 10k that return only 18 have an altSubject which is why I'm disappointed that the original case + function takes 5 minutes to run.

Answer (score 2):

"how to use a user defined mask in a column when the mask could be a combination of fields and text".

This is the best I can do and get good performance.

The table defines Subject, AltSubject and DisplaySubject.

A trigger sets the DisplaySubject based on the other two fields.

The trigger must reference the specific column names, so it needs to be regenerated every time columns are added. Maybe a nightly job?

```
create table myTable (
  id number, 
  subject varchar2(64), 
  altSubject varchar2(128),
  displaySubject varchar2(128),
  partNumber varchar2(16), 
  serialNumber varchar2(16), 
  startDate date, 
  endDate date
);

create or replace procedure generate_mytable_trigger is
l_newline constant varchar2(1) := chr(10);
l_text clob := to_clob(
'create or replace trigger mytable_displaysubject
before insert or update on mytable
for each row
declare
  lt_column_names sys.odcivarchar2list;
begin
  if :new.subject is not null then
    :new.altsubject := null;
    :new.displaysubject := :new.subject;
    return;
  end if;
  :new.displaysubject := :new.altsubject;
  -- start lines to be generated');
l_end_text constant varchar2(4000) := 
'-- end lines to be generated
  return;
end mytable_displaysubject;';
begin
  for rec in (
    select l_newline ||
      ':new.displaysubject := replace(:new.displaysubject, ''#'||column_name||'#'', :new.'||column_name||');'
      as text
    from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'MYTABLE'
    and column_name not in ('SUBJECT','ALTSUBJECT','DISPLAYSUBJECT')
  ) loop
    l_text := l_text || rec.text;
  end loop;
  l_text := l_text || l_newline || l_end_text;
  execute immediate l_text;
end;
/

exec generate_mytable_trigger;
```

Now a little test:

```
insert into mytable(id, subject, altsubject, partnumber, serialnumber, startdate, enddate)
select 1, 'test',null,'xyz','123',sysdate, sysdate+1 from dual
union all 
select 2, null,'PN: #PARTNUMBER#','abc','789',sysdate, sysdate+1 from dual
union all 
select 3, null,'PN: #PARTNUMBER#, SN: #SERIALNUMBER#','qsdf','789',sysdate, sysdate+1 from dual
union all 
select 3, null,'PN: #PARTNUMBER#, ??: #BADCOLUMN#','qsdf','789',sysdate, sysdate+1 from dual;
commit;

select subject, altsubject, displaysubject from mytable;

SUBJECT   ALTSUBJECT                             DISPLAYSUBJECT              
test                                               test                         
           PN: #PARTNUMBER#                        PN: abc                      
           PN: #PARTNUMBER#, SN: #SERIALNUMBER#    PN: qsdf, SN: 789            
           PN: #PARTNUMBER#, ??: #BADCOLUMN#       PN: qsdf, ??: #BADCOLUMN#
```

Comment: This has potential. I like the coldfusion #variable# parse thing you've got going. I'm not a huge fan of the display column, we tossed that idea around and decided it would be a list resort. Currently I've got it running in a few seconds using a temp table but there is potential for performance problems as the rows with masks grows as it builds the temp table. **psudo:** `insert into temp select id, subject where altSubject is null` then I add the masked rows in one at a time in a loop. join temp table to get the subject in the query. 15 seconds @ 10k records. slow but not 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a recent version of Oracle: congratulations. So use it: virtual columns!

```
create table myTable (
  id number, 
  subject varchar2(32), 
  altSubject varchar2(64)
    generated always as (case when subject is null then 'SN: '||serialnumber end), 
  partNumber varchar2(16), 
  serialNumber varchar2(16), 
  startDate date, 
  endDate date
);

insert into mytable(id, subject, partnumber, serialnumber, startdate, enddate)
select 1, 'test','xyz','123',sysdate, sysdate+1 from dual
union all 
select 2, null,'abc','789',sysdate, sysdate+1 from dual;

select ID, coalesce(SUBJECT, ALTSUBJECT) subject,
  PARTNUMBER, SERIALNUMBER, STARTDATE, ENDDATE
from mytable;

ID SUBJECT  PARTNUMBER  SERIALNUMBER  STARTDATE           ENDDATE            
-- -------- ----------- ------------- ------------------- -------------------
 1 test     xyz         123           2019-12-18 13:09:10 2019-12-19 13:09:10
 2 SN: 789  abc         789           2019-12-18 13:09:10 2019-12-19 13:09:10
```

That may very well be overkill. You could always get rid of the extra column and say:

```
select ID, coalesce(SUBJECT, 'SN: '||serialnumber) subject,
  PARTNUMBER, SERIALNUMBER, STARTDATE, ENDDATE
from mytable;
```

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Comment: my issue is that depending on what type of document I'm looking at the altSubject is different so I'm trying to pull it from the table as an optional setting to the document. It might be `'SN: '|| serialnumber` or `someColumn || '[' || anotherColumn || ']'` or whatever the customer would like to see as the alt subject.

Comment: I thought so. Don't do that. That is code, not data. Ask the customer to define document types and what they want to see as the alternate subject for each type. Then code those alternatives in a CASE expression.  Good grief, if the alternate subject varies with each document then why not just enter 'SN: 789' as the subject???

Comment: the application allows me to add a document, sometimes it has a subject, sometimes it doesn't. sometimes I have to add a column to suite the document requirement but it's all done automatically. if the document doesn't have a subject the system needs to be able to substitute it with something else without having to change the code every time a new document type is created. (it's not actually a "document" it's a bit more complicated than that, i.e. a dynamic ticketing system) I'm open to suggestions but modifying the code every week isn't an option.

Comment: "if the alternate subject varies with each document then why not just enter 'SN: 789' as the subject" as I was saying it's a simple example. Ticket types may not have a "subject" but the main subject might be `manual number` or `service instruction` which is selected from a drop down, or a combination of fields. The majority of tickets use the `subject` field but some do not and I need a way to handle it without having to modify the application every time a customer adds a new ticket type with custom fields.

Comment: "the main subject might be manual number or service instruction which is selected from a drop down, or a combination of fields." Then the user "enters" a value through the choice of a drop down! So just calculate the result of that choice and put it in the field, instead of putting a bit of code in the field to calculate the result every time. By the way, how are you going to add new custom fields to the drop down without changing the application??

Comment: they are added as the user defines them, this application uses ddl, another uses json columns. My question isn't how to add the columns (I've asked other questions about showing data that may or may not be in the form) I just need to know how to use a user defined mask in a column when the mask could be a combination of fields and text.

Comment: OK, I'll add another answer on "how to use a user defined mask in a column when the mask could be a combination of fields and text".